# JPEG Encoding. How to Encode RLE(AC) with Huffman algorithm

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code, encoder

I want to create Jpeg encoder class From RGB array to jpeg file.
I got stuck on moment When RLE(AC) converted by Huffman code.
I Have Huffman function, whitch input is (symbol1,amount1),(symbol2,amount2) and so on....
I also know that RLE(AC) - is simple (amount of zeros,number1),(amountof zeros,number2).
The question is - How prepare RLE(AC) for my Huffman function whitch expect (number,freq),(number,freq)?
Please help

Comment: Have you read the standard?

Comment: No, where to get it?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf